# Configuring Confirmation mail host in Rails Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I have setup an rails application using devise to implement a simple user sign up and sign in functionality.I have included confirmation mail to confirm the sign up.The confirmation mail works fine in my localhost,but if I confirms the account from other machines it returns error.What should I do to change my mail host???

This is how I set up my action mailer

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

This isthe confirmation.html.erb file :

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>


 <b> <h1> <font color="RED">Q-</font>Link </h1> </b>  

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

Comment: When you say "Other machines" what are you referring to? Other PC's that you do development on, or other servers?

Comment: Other machines means others systems in my network

Comment: You still haven't answer my question. I don't know if other systems in your network is servers or just local PCs.

Comment: Not server..they are local pC's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working locally and you don't have a mail server setup (which is probably the case), emails will not get sent.

However, to make sure your app is working correctly, when an email should get sent, you will see in the log that it actually generates the html for the email, it just doesn't send it.

Answer (score 0):

add ip address of the machine instead of local host

Comment: Tried it...Not Working...:(